# Get all objects (artists) drawn on a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm hoping to setup a method which can convert a normal figure (dark lines, white/transparent background) to a pseudo-inverted figure (light lines, black/transparent background).  I could just post-process invert the image, but directly inverted colors look awful, so I'd like to instead (try to) create a mapping from one set of colors to another, and then apply this to all artists which have been added to (all axes on) a figure.

**Is there a way to access all objects (e.g. text, scatter, lines, ticklabels, etc) that have been added to a figure?**

---

Edit: my motivation is to automatically create white-background and black-background versions of figures.  White-background figures will always (I think) be required for *publications* (for example), while black-background figures may be better for *presentations* (i.e. talk slides).  While it wouldn't be ***that*** much trouble to setup a flag, and change each color based on that, e.g.

```
if dark:
    col_line = 'cyan'
    col_bg = 'black'
else:
    col_line = 'red'
    col_bg = 'white'

# ... plot ...
```

It would be much cooler and more convenient (despite overhead) to do something like,

```
fig.savefig('dark.pdf')
invert(fig)
fig.savefig('light.pdf')
```

Comment: This sounds a bit like a workaround solution for something else. If you want to have a cherry cake you wouldn't prepare an apple pie and exchange all apples for cherries; same here: why not make sure the objects are already created with the correct properties?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest because I want to have both versions of a figure without having to replot everything manually, changing parameters as needed (though, that may end up being the best/easiest solution).  I've added some clarification on the question.

Answer (score 7):

Recursively call `.get_children()`, stop when the returned list is empty.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand a bit though?  i.e. what type of objects are returned and what I can all that on?

Comment: `.get_children()` is a method that returns all artists that hang off the artist parent. E.g. `plt.gcf().get_children()` returns the axes and the background patch; plt.gca().get_children() returns the axis background artist, the spine artists, the axes artists, the x/y-label artists, the background patch artists, and any plot elements such as lines, markers, legends (many of these elements have children that are artists themselves, e.g. a legend typically contains several artists).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different style or change an existing style to your needs instead of changing all properties of all possible artists yourself.

E.g. you might start with the  `"dark_background"` style and then adjust some further parameters using [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("dark_background")

style = {"lines.linewidth" : 2,
         "axes.facecolor" : "#410448"}
plt.rcParams.update(style)

plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, and I hadn't considered using the `style` functionality; but I am hoping for a different solution.